# Add var into css class

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component, css-animations

I'm currently writing a component that is making an animation in a loop, the animation time is a props passed to the component.

My problem is the following:
The animation is made in CSS:

```
animate:{
   -webkit-transition: 10.0s !important;
   -moz-transition: 10.0s !important;
   -o-transition: 10.0s !important;
   transition: 10.0s !important;
}
```

I would want to pass the duration inside this class declaration but it seems impossible and I'm using these CSS tricks to restart the animation: https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/ that is including the usage of a class.

Is there any way to init a class with vars in Vue.js or to make a CSS animation in a loop with duration as a parameter ?

Comment: You can do something like  document.getElementById("myDIV").style.transitionDuration = this.props.duration

Comment: CSS is static, so you only can change it in runtime modifying the element in the DOM

Comment: Yes it's what I was thinking, is there a nice way to reset the animation in Vue.js without the css tricks above or to edit a class already declared into the dom ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

css isn't static if you use variables
could you do

```
:root{
   --primary-animation:10s;
}

animate:{
   -webkit-transition: var(--primary-animation) !important;
   -moz-transition: var(--primary-animation) !important;
   -o-transition: var(--primary-animation) !important;
   transition: var(--primary-animation) !important;
}
```

and on component

```
created(){
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--primary-animation', this.myCustomProperty+"s")

}
```